# How can i access woocommerce order variables inside shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am adding a shortcode from wordpress to woocommerce email template.

```
do_shortcode('[sample_test name="additional_gift_msg"]);
```

Then i am using this to display the value in email. I am able to display value.

```
    function th_email_shortcode_handler( $atts ) {
        if ( ! empty( $atts['name'] ) ) {
            $field = $atts['name'];
            echo 'Found me';
        }
    }

add_shortcode('sample_test','th_email_shortcode_handler');
```

But i need `$order` or `$order_id` inside this handler function to take some value from post meta. How can i use those variables? The shortcode handler function is in functions.php

Also i tried the following but still $order_id is empty.

```
do_shortcode('[sample_test name="additional_gift_msg" order_id=' . $order->get_id() . ']');
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will do the trick.

```
function th_email_shortcode_handler( $atts ) {
        if ( ! empty( $atts['name'] ) ) {
            $field = $atts['name'];
            echo 'Found me';
        }

    global $wp;

    $order_id  = absint( $wp->query_vars['order_id'] );

    if ( empty($order_id) || $order_id == 0 )
        return; // Exit;

    return $order_id;
    }

add_shortcode('sample_test','th_email_shortcode_handler');
```

Comment: since $order in available in woocommerce email templates won't i get it directly ?

Comment: `do_shortcode('[sample_test name="additional_gift_msg" order_id=' . $order->get_id() . ']');` here are you not getting `order_id`?

Comment: The `do_shortcode` is in my email template. When i `var_dump` just before `do_Shortcode` line i get the value but i cannot get inside the function

Comment: The `do_shortcode` is in my email template. When i `var_dump` just before `do_Shortcode` line i get the value but i cannot get inside the function

Comment: Yes. Not working. `$order_id` inside function when `var_dump` gives `int 0`